# Query to find match where constraints can be in any of the given columns

Tags: sql

I made a database for all the items in a game. An item could have 0 - 3 attributes. Those attributes are stored in `Atttribute1, Atttribute2, Atttribute3` columns respectively.

The order of the attributes is important meaning that I can't just simply swap `attribute1` with `attribute3`.
`Attributes` are represented by ID and they are stored in `Attribute` table.

When searching, I want to give user the option to find match items which contains the three attributes they specified even if they are not in the correct order.

Example : item1 has attribute 1 2 2, if user specifies 2 2 1 then its a match but 3 2 2 is not.

for null cases: null 2 2 and 2 2 2 is not a match

I thought about using
`Attribute1 in (input1, input2, input3) and Attribute 2 in (input1, input2, input3) ...`
but then 1 2 2 and 1 1 2 would be matched.

I also thought about union all three columns into a new temp table but that might destroy index and slow down search speed.

Comment: You should be storing the three attributes in a junction table, with one row per item and per attribute (along with the priority).

Comment: @GordonLinoff unfortunately the attributes has no priority and the order matters.

Comment: . . By "priority" I meant what you call "order".

Comment: @GordonLinoff yea I got what you meant after a second thought. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be storing the attributes in a junction table, with one row per item and per attribute.

But, you can do what you want using explicit logic:

```
where (Attribute1 = input1 and Attribute2 = input2 and Attribute3 = input3) or
      (Attribute1 = input1 and Attribute2 = input3 and Attribute3 = input2) or
      (Attribute1 = input2 and Attribute2 = input1 and Attribute3 = input3) or
      (Attribute1 = input2 and Attribute2 = input3 and Attribute3 = input1) or
      (Attribute1 = input3 and Attribute2 = input1 and Attribute3 = input2) or
      (Attribute1 = input3 and Attribute2 = input2 and Attribute3 = input1)
```